# Eclipse is read-only after attaching for debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm using eclipse to write a Java Maven application. For debugging, I attach to a remote java application. However, after this, I cannot modify the source files. I have to restart Ecplise. Does this happend to anyone?

Comment: Are you sure that you're seeing *your* source file and not the source for a library? I.e. if you create a Java library project and add it to another project, the projects are compiled independently. When you debug the application project, you'll see all the sources in that project, but you'll also see source files from the library project's generated jar that's attached to the library project. These source files are different than the ones in the library project itself and are also read-only

Comment: I've stumbled on this one when developing an Android app that used a lot of libraries and the files that Eclipse was showing were files for jars added to the main project, not files from the library project that was included (although the source code was the same:) )

Comment: @lucian.pantelimon yes, that was it! Stupid me! Multumesc

Comment: Cu placere (You're welcome)! :) I'll copy-paste the comments as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you're seeing *your* source file and not the source for a library?

I.e. if you create a Java library project and add it to another project, the projects are compiled independently. When you debug the application project, you'll see all the sources in that project, but you'll also see source files from the library project's *generated jar* that's attached to the library project. These source files are different than the ones in the library project itself and are also read-only.

I've stumbled on this one when developing an Android app that used a lot of libraries and the files that Eclipse was showing were files for jars added to the main project, not files from the library project that was included (although the source code was the same:) )